# When sharing photos on Facebook, how does Facebook prioritize sharing methods? Certain methods don't show up in friends' feeds as often

Tags: facebook, if-this-then-that, flickr, facebook-photos, photo-sharing

What I mean is, if I add photos to an album via an external source such as iPhoto, Flickr, or IFTTT, it is rare that I'll receive any likes or comments. When I share a photo directly to Facebook from my phone, I'll get a fair number of likes and comments. Maybe the better question is, how does Facebook prioritize which type of shares, in general, show up in friends' feeds.

Comment: My personal observation is that posts from apps (any of them) are ranked pretty low when Facebook decides what to show in newsfeeds. Posts made directly through OS integration, through the website, or through a Facebook app, get ranked pretty high. Nothing authoritative, just my observation.